# XML Sitemap for Multi-site

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

I have generated a XML sitemap for multi-site using a free online tool - https://www.xml-sitemaps.com. I have downloaded XML file for each site and placed sitemap.xml at the root (\src\sitemap.xml) for main site and for sub-sites placed at \src\sites\sub-site-name\sitemap.xml.

When I access the main site at www.main-site.com/sitemap.xml, I get the correct sitemap.xml but for sub-sites (www.sub-site.com/sitemap.xml), I am getting the sitemap of the main site every time. How can I access the sitemap.xml file for sub-sites at www.sub-site.com/sitemap.xml. I can access the sitemap.xml for sub-sites if I go to the path: www.sub-site.com/sites/sub-site.com/sitemap.xml.

Comment: Why not use XMLSitemap module or Simple XML Sitemap? A static file will not stay up to date at all.

Comment: Or just submit the correct path for each to the search engines. You don't need it to be implied

Comment: My client requested to use the free online tool as they required the detailed listing in sitemap including all the links and file uploads. I already gave the detailed listing using Simple XML sitemap but that doesn't list down the file uploads in it. What should I do now.

Comment: Create symlinks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I got proper sitemaps for each sub-site by using the code below:

Syntax: RewriteRule /?sitemap.xml %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitemaps/%{HTTP_HOST}.xml [L]
My way: RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap/%{HTTP_HOST}.xml [L]